# Syntax error when trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL to check if a given POINT is inside a POLYGON but I get the error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7`

This is my query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IsInsidePolygon(
    IN polygon_coordinates VARCHAR(200),
    IN point_coordinates VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        polygonData GEOMETRYCOLLECTION; 
    DECLARE 
        pointData POINT;
    SET
        polygonData = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POLYGON((', polygon_coordinates, '))')
        );
    SET
        pointData = ST_GEOFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POINT(', point_coordinates, ')')
        );
    SELECT
        post_id
    FROM
        wp_postmeta
    WHERE
        ST_CONTAINS(polygonData, pointData);
END;
```

I'm a beginner in SQL so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What query tool are you running this in?

Comment: I'm using 'phpmyadmin'.

Answer (score 1):

You had an undeclared variable `coordinates` that is subbed with `polygon_coordinates` and a missing semicolon after the query at the end:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IsInsidePolygon(
    IN polygon_coordinates VARCHAR(200),
    IN point_coordinates VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        polygonData GEOMETRYCOLLECTION; 
    DECLARE 
        pointData POINT;
    SET
        polygonData = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POLYGON((', polygon_coordinates, '))')
        );
    SET
        pointData = ST_GEOFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POINT(', point_coordinates, ')')
        );
    SELECT
        post_id
    FROM
        wp_postmeta
    WHERE
        ST_CONTAINS(polygonData, pointData);
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the ones you mentioned but I still get the same error at the same line. Will update the question now.

Comment: You might need to set the DELIMITER to something else at the start of the script/in phpmyadmin e.g. set it to `//` and then adjust your `END` to be `END//`. You could also try the "Add Routine" facility instead (Routines tab)

Comment: That was it! All I had to do was add "DELIMITER $$" at the beginning. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo in the naming of one of the variable and a missing 'DELIMITER $$' at the beginning.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE IsInsidePolygon(
    IN polygon_coordinates VARCHAR(200),
    IN point_coordinates VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        polygonData GEOMETRYCOLLECTION; 
    DECLARE 
        pointData POINT;
    SET
        polygonData = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POLYGON((', polygon_coordinates, '))')
        );
    SET
        pointData = ST_GEOFROMTEXT(
            CONCAT('POINT(', point_coordinates, ')')
        );
    SELECT
        post_id
    FROM
        wp_postmeta
    WHERE
        ST_CONTAINS(polygonData, pointData);
END
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Ps. This query was run in "phpmyadmin".